# how does bracket operator work in python?

Tags: python

I was reviewing a code written in python, part of it looks like this.

```
n = len(A)
T = n * [False]
for i in xrange(n + 1):
    T[A[i]] = True
```

which A is an array of integer values. I assume the second line creates a list of size n with values of false, but it is not clear to me how T[A[i]] works. Does it access the element of T at A[i]? But A[i] is not necessarily between 0 and n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed accessing element of `T` at `A[i]`. And it's indeed true that `A[i]` might not be between 0 and n. But that's what the code does.

So if you are expecting that `T[A[i]]` should work, probably there are some code before, that ensures `A[i]` always between 0 and n.

Comment: Then I assume it is the missing assumption of the code that members of A are in the range of 0 to n.

Answer (score 1):

`A[i]` is probably a number, and yes, if its length is `>n`, you'll get an IndexError.

The actual variable passed is something like:

```
T[number]
```

Here is a little example, we have the `A` variable:

```
>>> A = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

And we have the `T` variable as:

```
>>> T = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

And then we do the loop:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
    print T[A[i]]
```

Result:

```
E
D
C
B
A
```

As long as `A[i]` is not higher than n, it'll be fine.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

See farid,

You are confused about T[A[i]].
Let me expalin you...

A and T both are arrays.

for T[A[i]]=True, 
A[i] is an index for array T.

Because length of T is n only.
SO if array A having all integers values < n(lenght of ARRAY T).
The code will work fine.

But if not:
Python will through ***index out of range*** exception

Comment: there was no assumption for the values in A. and n is just the size of A. That is what confused me.